# Type casting fails in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting

The type casting here succeeds

```
id object = [NSMutableArray array];
NSURLConnection *urlCon = (NSURLConnection*)object;

if ([urlCon isKindOfClass:[NSURLConnection class]])
    NSLog(@"urlCon is NSURLConnection");
else if ([urlCon isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]])
    NSLog(@"urlCon is NSMutableArray"); // this is called
```

actually since 'object' is of type `NSMutableArray`, the type casting for `NSURLConnection` should fail. but it is successful and `urlCon` still points to `NSMutableArray`, then what is the use of TypeCasting?

Answer (score 8):

There are two separate issues: One is what type the variable is. The other is what type the underlying object is.

In Objective-C, casting of object pointers doesn't change what the underlying object is. And casting in Objective-C doesn't "succeed" or "fail". It's merely telling the compiler to allow you to treat the variable as if it were actually pointing to an object of the casted type. You generally do this in cases where (a) you have some knowledge of the underlying object that the compiler couldn't reasonably know, and (b) you want to be able to invoke some particular method of some class without the compiler complaining about it. Clearly, that's not the case here, where you've cast the `urlCon` variable to expect `object` to be a `NSURLConnection`, which it isn't.

But `isKindOfClass` is a runtime check, which actually looks at what type the underlying object is, and doesn't care what type the variable was cast to.

---

One common pattern will use `isKindOfClass` too determine if an object is a of a particular class, and if so, then will cast it to that particular type so that you can then use methods and/or properties of that class without warnings from the compiler.

So you'll often see this sort of pattern in processing network requests:

```
NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {             // check to see if response is `NSHTTPURLResponse`
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;  // if so, cast `NSURLResponse` to `NSHTTPURLResponse`
        NSInteger statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode;                   // now you can use `statusCode` property of `NSHTTPURLResponse`

        if (statusCode != 200) {
            // Non 200 status code ... so handle HTTP error accordingly here
        }
    }

    // carry on
}];
[task resume];
```

There are slightly simpler renditions of this pattern, but hopefully it illustrates the idea: You cast when you know (or have programmatically confirmed) something about the type of the object that is pointed to, and you just want to get the compiler on the same page so that you can now use it. You can use `isKindOfClass` as a runtime check to confirm that it is, indeed, that type, but the cast lets you use it as such.

Comment: Apparently it's actually a feature rather than an issue according to Apple's Obj-C marketing fluff (I'm not convinced of whether such behavior is a good thing or bad). Question about the last sentence, is `KindOf` a runtime facility or compile time? — some Apple devs told me it was compile time, so just wondering. I presume it's all variations of `KindOf`'s too, not just `isKindOfClass`, correct me if I'm wrong? thx :)

Comment: @l'L'l - The `isKindOfClass` and `isMemberOfClass` are definitely determined at run time, not at compile time. In fact, it's most commonly used in situations where you can't know what the object was at compile time, but rather only at runtime. The Apple engineers you were talking to must have been talking about something else. Anyway, I've revised example to show practical example of runtime class test (used to make sure that the subsequent cast will be safe).

Comment: Yes that does seem logical and your example is helpful; In case you wondered about the Apple reference or where it had been mentioned [here's the transcript](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/202/?time=537). During presentations I know it's common for a speaker to jump back and forth on topics, so I likely interpreted it in the wrong context.

Comment: Yep, they're talking about the Swiftification of the Cocoa API. Swift takes type safety far more seriously than Objective-C ever did. And they're right, that enforcing type safety in the language (ie. at compile time), is a great improvement. But we still need runtime checks (like above), and you can use `isKindOfClass` (or in Swift, the `is` type-checking keyword or `as?` to gracefully handle cast failures).

Answer (score 2):

What you're experiencing is entirely expected behaviour.

Casting an object of type X, to type Y, does **not** change the object, it merely forces the object of type X, to look like an object of type Y, even though it's of type X.

What you've done in your example, will most likely invoke lot's of undefined behaviour, if you start calling any function on the object, since `NSMutableArray` is not a sub- or superclass of `NSURLConnection`.

What you've done is a C style cast. In C, you can cast any two pointer types into each other, there are no checks involved to verify it.

Comment: @Sulthan In C, pointer types can freely be cast into each other, without any checks. C is not C++. This compiles without warnings: `NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray new]; NSURLConnection *con = (NSURLConnection*)arr;`